# Why does Serverfault always show the Add Comment box on answers?

Tags: support, comments

I'm thinking it's because I just registered and don't have enough reputation to Add a Comment, so on my own question it automatically shows the boxes rather than the link.

But that doesn't quite make sense to me, wouldn't it be just as easy to show the link rather than show all these boxes? Was there a design reason behind this or is this just a bug?

[image: I remembered the freehand circles this time.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many new users were confused as to how they should respond to answers posted to their questions, and made the mistake of posting answers consisting of replies instead of commenting.

So now the comments are made more obvious for new users.

#### See: [Rep-requirement for Answering Own Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/rep-requirement-for-answering-own-question/36337#36337)

Comment: yes, this was shog9's very idea. A good one too! Note that this *only* applies to new-ish users when viewing questions they own. I think the threshold is 200 rep.

Comment: Now that I know the reason behind this, I have to agree. If I weren't an older user who is easily confused, the comment boxes would have been a nice help.